# How to make thumbnail images same size while different resolution in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

```
<!-- START OF FIRST LITTER GALLERY-->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstModal">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="firstModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div id="ffl" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="ffl" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="ffl" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="ffl" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#ffl" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#ffl" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
      <p>THUMBNAIL TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF FIRST LITTER GALLERY-->

<!-- START OF SECOND LITTER GALLERY-->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="thumbnail flexbox">
    <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secondModal">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="secondModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div id="sfl" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="sfl" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="sfl" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="sfl" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://animatedanatomy.com/images/16-9-dummy-image6.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#sfl" data-slide="prev">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#sfl" data-slide="next">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
      <p>THUMBNAIL TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF SECOND LITTER GALLERY-->
```

Here is an example that I have created.

I have created my first website with bootstrap and I want to make it look as good as possible so now I hit something that cannot make without help.

The trouble is that I would like to have my images inside thumbnail same size even if they are different resolution. I used max/min-width/height but this does not solve the problem. Tried overflow but in that case my caption was under image.

What I am looking for:

In case if the image is not the right size I would like to have this image centred and rest of the image overflowed under the caption and thumbnail. 
Also how to make my images in modal window original size.

[This is the page that I have created so it may help to understand my problem](http://stronadlapsow.cba.pl).

Comment: Create a sample in jsfiddle. Replace the image-links with links to real images that show the problem. use google images or lorempixel.com.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wcqysnjn/6/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

The fastest way would be to change in css

```
 .thumbnail img {
     display: flex; /*remove this*/
     float: left; /*remove this*/
     margin-left: 50%; /*added this*/
     transform: translateX(-50%); /*added this*/
 }
```

Comment: well it haven't helped yet. they are still different size